# SendMessage to Windows Explorer address bar

Tags: api, winapi, pinvoke, sendmessage

How to SendMessage to Windows Explorer address bar in C#?

Comment: Do you actually mean the Windows Explorer address bar, or do you mean the Internet Explorer URL bar ?

Answer (score 0):

call SendMessage to the window handle

However the response is not documented anywhere in Windows SDK. Don't bet you business on undocumented behavior. If you need to control the address bar in your code, I suggest you to write your own browser or host the webbrowser control in your application.